# Excel Formula to check set of cells for specific text then check and assign values to other set of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Alright I am trying to make a formula to check a set of cells for a specific word then if that word is found check a corresponding cell and assign a value depending on what is in that cell. Then take the average of the destination cell based on the values provided.

So for example. I am searching A1:A100 for the text farm. So if farm is in A1 then I check the value in B1. The values have four possibilities 0, 1, 2 and 3. If the Value is 3 then add 1 to the destination cell. If it is any of the other values it equals 0. Then take the average of the destination cell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In example, what is destination cell? Why do you add 1 if value is 3, and 0 otherwise. What do you mean with average of destination cell, average of a single value is the value itself, no? Please rephrase and add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely what you want to achieve. Take it from here:

[image]

The formula in cell D2 is

=IF(VLOOKUP("farm",$A$1:$B$10,2,FALSE)=3,C2+1,C2)

Vlookup finds the word "farm" in column A and returns the value from column B in the same row. Destination cell is cell C2 and has a value of 100. If the found value next to "farm" equals 3, add 1 to the value from C2, otherwise add nothing to C2.

Now, please edit your question and clarify about the average. What do you want to average?